# Do a Factory Reset on an HTC Desire 530 with a missing Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset

I got an HTC Desire 530 for free with the data of the previous owner and I want to completely wipe it. The thing is, the device for some reason does not has the Recovery environment, which the 530 needs to do a factory reset.

How can I restore an HTC Desire 530 with a missing recovery? (either via installing a 3rd party Recovery like TWRP)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119586/discussion-on-question-by-lemon-do-a-factory-reset-on-an-htc-desire-530-with-a-m).

Comment: @alecxs I have undeleted the room. It was auto deleted. Try that chat room link again.